# Magento index fails after processing

Tags: magento, indexing

My catalog URL has not run for over a month. I have tried running in both from Magento and the command line.

When running from Magento it times out on the front end but when I go back to it I can see that it is processing.

When running from the command line I can see in Magento it says processing and the command line also tells me that it has successfully rebuild the index.

However, after doing these several times Magento is still telling me that the Catalog URL Rewrites index was last run on 20/4/13.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following 2 steps after taking a full file system & database backup of your site.

1. Repair your Magento database: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool
2. Rebuild your Magento index from the command line: http://www.atwix.com/magento/process-magento-indexes-from-command-line/